# Divide values from a class extending number

Tags: java

I have a class which extends number.

```
public class Quantity extends Number{

}
```

And the class as,

```
public class Test{

Quantity tkphMaxValue;
Quantity tkphValue;

 public Test(Quantity tkphValue, Quantity maxValue){
    this.tkphValue= tkphValue;
    this.maxValue= maxValue;

}


 public Quantity getTkphValue() {
    return tkphValue;
}

public void setTkphValue(Quantity tkphValue) {
    this.tkphValue = tkphValue;
}


 public Quantity getTkphMaxValue() {
    return tkphMaxValue;
}

public void setTkphMaxValue(Quantity maxValue) {
    this.tkphMaxValue = maxValue;
}

}
```

I need to divide `((getTkphValue()/getTkphMaxValue())*100)` to get the percentage value.
How can I convert the Quantity object to number?

Comment: Maybe you should use doubleValue method to convert Test class attributes to double and then divide them.

Comment: Please clarify your question !

Comment: A `Number` is an object that has  `byteValue()`, `shortValue()`, `intValue()`, `floatValue()`, and `doubleValue()` methods.  Why do your `Quantity` objects need to have all of those methods?  Why can't you just use `double`?

Comment: @jameslarge The `Quantity` is used almost thousand times in my code. Each has different uses. I am going with what @peterremec has given. Trying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
((getTkphValue().doubleValue()/getTkphMaxValue().doubleValue())*100)
```

Before you do, make sure that tkphMaxValue and tkphValue are not null.